# Is this integral analytically solvable?

Tags: calculus, integration

Is there an analytic solution to the following integral?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\left(\frac{1}{1+e^{-\gamma x}}\right)^{\alpha-1}\left(\frac{1}{1+e^{\gamma x}}\right)^{\beta-1}dx$$

The function to be intregrated is the multiplication of a normal distribution $e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$ and a Beta distribution $y^{\alpha-1}(1-y)^{\beta-1}$, where the y passed to the Beta distribution is a sigmoid transformation $1/(1+e^{-\gamma x})$ of x.

In case there is no analytic solution, can the integral be simplified in one way or the other? Thanks!

Comment: [integralrechner.de](https://www.integralrechner.de/); although I think that this cannot be simplified

Comment: Thanks for the helpful link! Yes, putting in the above integral as follows: e^((-(x-m)^2)/(2s^2))(1/(1+e^(-g*x)))^(a-1)(1/(1+e^(g*x)))^(b-1) does not lead to a solution on this website.

Comment: Okay that is a rare site and it means that your problem is very complicated. But the Website usually does great work.